# Getting duration for streaming video

Tags: java, android, video, media-player, media

I am using VideoView, and in `setVideoUri` I am using a link of streaming url.
In most of devices I am able to `getDuration` and it is working fine. But with the Samsumg Galaxy Tab, `getDuration` is returning `0`, and as a result, I am not able to show the total time and my seek bar is messed up.

So what can be done to get the duration?

I have tried few alternatives like when `getCurrentPosition() > 0`, as when the video data loads from the streaming url, there again I am calling `getDuration`, but still no use.
I am getting 0 as a value.